# Problem with $SL(2)$ isometric action on a compact homogeneous space

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory

Let $G=SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, fix any left-invariant Riemannian metric $g$ on $G$. Let $\Gamma$ be a cocompact discrete subgroup of $G$ and $X=G/\Gamma$. Because $\Gamma$ acts by isometries $g$ descends to $X$ (call it $g'$) and the action of $G$ on $X$ must preserve $g'$, since being an isometry (in the Riemannian sense) is a local fact and $X$ is locally just like $G$.

Hence, we get an isometric $G$-action on a compact Riemannian manifold $X$ which also preserves the Riemannian volume $\mu_{g'}$ on $X$. But this shouldn't be possible. The isometry group of a compact $X$ is compact, so the unitary representation of $G$ on $L^2(X,\mu_{g'})$ given by the aforementioned action factors through a compact group unitary representation and must then split into finite-dimensional components. This is a contradiction with the well-known fact that $G$ has no finite-dimensional unitary representations.

Where's the error in my reasoning?

EDIT: Just noticed my argument assumes $g$ is both left and right invariant.

Comment: Ok, I see the error. $g$ need not be bi-invariant. I guess this proves $G$ can't have a bi-invariant metric.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G$ is endowed with a bi invariant metric, it induces on its Lie algebra $sl(2)$ a scalar product invariant by the adjoint representation. This implies that the image of $SL(2)$ by the adjoint representation is conjugated to a subgroup of $SO(3)$ and this is not true since the adjoint representation has unbounded orbits.